# Update all rows in a column using data from another column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Content` model, where each piece of content has a source. Currently, the `Content` model has a `link` column for the URL and a `link_text` column for the name of the source, i.e. a user has to manually type in the name and URL of the source. I want to change this to be able to automatically enter a name, once a URL is provided. Here's what I did:

> I made a `Source` model. The Source model contains all the `name` and `domain` of every source used for content. This is related to Content as follows: A `Source` has_many pieces of `Content`, while `Content` belongs to a `Source`.

Therefore, I need to replace the `link_text` column with a `source_id` column. Then I need to set the value of the `source_id` column using the `link` column in the contents table.

i.e. I will compare the URL in the `link` column (in the contents table) to the URL in the `domain` column (in the sources table) and set the `source_id` for each row of `Content` accordingly.

**How could I go about doing that?**

One other thing to consider is that, I want to set the `source_id` in a migration, so that I can make the change to existing data in my production application as well.

I have created 1 migration to add a `source_id` column to my contents table and another migration to set all the data in that column for all existing records - It's that second migration that I'm unsure about.

Comment: And what columns identify link? I.e. `content.link == source.domain` ?

Comment: No, the link and the domain are not equal. `content.link` is something like `https://www.example.com/some/page` and `source.domain` is like `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Not good. Then you have to write migration with ruby code and slow cycle, instead of 1 SQL UPDATE.

Comment: Oh OK. In that case, is there any better way to go about this @pavel ? i.e. A way that I can easily make the change on my production database as well?

Comment: You have to design your tables like `Source.link` is same as `Content.link`. Then you can add `source_id` to Content, fill `sources` table with all your links, do update of Content(set `source_id` by `link`) and then add foreign key, index and `not null` constraint on `contents.source_id` column.

Comment: OK, but the way my data is set up, the source table only has the `domain` of a particular website. The `content.link` is a particular page on that website. I'm not too worried about a slow cycle or any performance impacts of the migration, since at the moment, I still have a small amount of data in production (the production app is also in use by a very small test group). So, in that case, would it be OK putting Ruby code in the migration? @pavel